# Show that the condition $f^{-1} f(A) = A$ implies a one-to-one mapping

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I am trying to show that a mapping $f: X \to Y$ that satisfies $f^{-1} f(A) = A$ for any $A \subset X$ is one-to-one.

I understand that in general $A \subseteq f^{-1} f(A)$. But I cannot understand why $f^{-1} f(A) = A$ would imply that $f$ is one-to-one.

For now all I can extract from the condition $f^{-1} f(A) = A$ is that $A = \{ x\in X : f(x) \in f(A) \}$. But I cannot see that writing $A$ in this way guarantees that any $x \in A$ maps to a unique $f(x) \in f(A)$.

Any clues on how to proceed?

Comment: If $f$ is not 1-1, witnessed by $f(p)=f(q)$, try $A=\{p\}$?

Comment: I think you're mistaken. In general, as you pointed: $A \subseteq f^{-1}(f(A))$. Now, if $f$ is injective, then $A = f^{-1}(f(A))$. I don't think there's any way we can obtain or discern the function's behaviour from a set. Are you reading Munkres' Topology book?

Comment: @SNJ The identity $f^{-1}[f[A]] =A$ means that for any subset $A$, if $x$ has its image in common with an element of $A$, then $x \in A$ already.

Comment: @SNJ I'm reading Simmons's 1963 "Introduction to Topology and Modern Analysis", which states that the implication is in both directions; $A = f^{-1} f(A) \Leftrightarrow$ $f$ is injective. Presently I'm concerned with the rightwards direction.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma That is exactly my point. If $A$ contains more than one element then I cannot see that the identity $A = f^{-1} f(A)$ guarantees that any two distinct elements $x, y \in A$ have distinct images $f(x)$ and $f(y)$.

Comment: If $f(p)=f(q)$ for $p \neq q$ define $A = \{p\}$ then $q \notin A$ but $q \in f^{-1}[f[A]]$ as $f(q) = f(p) \in f[A]$ which is a contradiction.

Comment: I see. It is quite crucial to consider a singleton $A := \{x\}$; $f^{-1} f(A) = A$ then implies that there can be no other $y \in X$ such that $f(y) \in f(A)$ (i.e. $f(y) = f(x)$.), as shown by @S.G below. Thank you for directing me towards singletons!

Comment: The question is not about topology, please, choose your tags carefully.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma thank you. I didn't know about the converse; learnt something today.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$f:X\to Y$ with the property $f^{-1} [f(A)] = A$ for any $A\subset X$.

$f^{-1}[ f(A)] =\{x\in X : f(x) \in f(A) \}$

Now, consider $ A=\{x\}$

$f^{-1} [f\{x\}] = \{y\in X : f(y) \in f\{x\}\}$

$=\{y\in X : f(y)=f(x)\}$

Using given condition,
$f^{-1} [f\{x\}]=\{x\}$

Now, we have to show $f:X \to Y $ is a 1-1 function.

Choose, any two points $x, y\in X$ such that $f(x) =f(y) $

So, $y \in X$ with $ f(x) =f(y)$ implies $y \in f^{-1} [f\{x\}]=\{x\}$.

$\implies y=x.$

For any two points $x, y \in X$ , $f(x) =f(y)\implies x=y$.

Hence,
$f:X \to Y $ is a 1-1 function.